# ¿Cómo agregar y que funcione un botón en las filas en Datatables, usando JQuer, y ajax para recuperar los datos de mysql?

Tags: jquery, datatables

soy nueva en Datatables, y quiero agregar un botón "Send Mail" a cada fila de mi tabla. Como ya estoy agregando "Delete", y "Update", decidí hacer algo parecido para agregar "Send Mail". He logrado que el botón aparezca, pero no funciona al hacer click.

En el archivo php en el cual cargo los datos de cada columna, agregué el botón de la siguiente forma:

```
$sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["QId"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row["QId"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="sendmail" id="'.$row["QId"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Send</button>';
    $data[] = $sub_array;
```

Y, como dije, el botón aparece bien. En el archivo de front-end, que usa jquery, agregué el funcionamiento del botón así:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
        var quote_id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"quoteadmin_delete.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{quote_id:quote_id},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return false;   
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.sendmail', function(){
        alert("dio click");
    });
```

Aquí muestro el botón delete, el cual si funciona, y el botón send mail, que agregué y no funciona.

Comment: Por lo que veo, solo te falta agregar la clase `sendmail` al botón, es decir, `<button type="button" name="sendmail" id="'.$row["QId"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs sendmail">Send</button>`

Comment: genial!, ese era el problema, muchísimas gracias